# Loading external SWFs into an Adobe AIR application - Best Practices?

Tags: apache-flex, air, sandbox

I've recently been slated with a task to port an existing Flash Player-base game to a desktop app for publication on the Steam platform. The Adobe AIR framework seems like a logical choice for distribution, especially given the latest updates in AIR 3. Given the fact that I'm relatively new to flash/flex development, I've read through a fair amount of AIR documentation on the Adobe site in order to gain a better understanding of what the task involves. In general, I think I have a decent idea of what needs to happen, but there are a couple of wrinkles that may affect if/how it is even possible to port to the AIR framework:

1. The AIR application will need to load the actual game client from an external server due to the quick turnaround time of the client development.
2. Since the AIR application will be deployed on Steam, I want to use the Captive Runtime bundling that's available in AIR 3.0, i.e. no need for the user to 'OK' a separate AIR installation.
3. Have minimal impact on code changes within the external SWF as I'm not the primary developer of the game.

My first priority is to figure out the best approach for loading an external game client SWF into an AIR application. Initially, I tried to utilize Loader.load(), but that resulted in the following exception:

```
SecurityError: Error #2070: Security sandbox violation: caller http://localhost/MyClient.swf cannot access Stage owned by app:/AS3_AIRTest.swf.
    at flash.media::SoundMixer$/set soundTransform()
    at com.company.client.sound::SFXManager$/load()
    at global/client.util::loadEmbeddedSounds()
    at MyClient()
```

The offending code is:

```
static public function load():void {
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = 
        new SoundTransform(Client.Settings.PlaySFX ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Upon hitting this exception, I decided to read up a bit more on the AIR / Flash player security domains. I have a much clearer understanding of why the exception occurred, but I'm still uncertain what the best approach would be to load the SWF and not receive the exception above.

After scouring through numerous posts on various forums, I found that a number of developers use Loader.loadBytes() to bring the SWF into the application sandbox. From an ease of implementation standpoint, I can see why many choose to go that route; however, I'm not inclined to pursue that approach due the potential dangers to user systems in the event that the external server is compromised.

The second approach that I've read about is that I can utilize a sandbox script bridge, and write an interface to grant certain privileges to the external client SWF. I'm hesitant to go this route at the moment because the game client is fairly complex, and I'm not entirely certain how much access it will require of the stage via different flash APIs. I haven't written this approach off as it sounds like it may be the best bet, but it could potentially be a large endeavor and I want to have minimal impact on the client SWF.

The final approach I've read about is by making an HTML AIR application. My understanding (sketchy at best) is that a SWF loaded via HTML (I believe in a frame/iframe) will have its own stage. My line of thinking is that if the HTML app loads a main page, which in turn has an iframe with SWF embed of the game client, then the client SWF will load in a remote security sandbox and have access to its own stage. My hope is that the SWF would behave as it does in the Flash Player.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Is my line of thinking correct about the HTML app?

   - Would the client SWF have access to its own stage and pretty much behave like it does in the Flash Player?
2. Can HTML-based AIR applications be bundled with the captive runtime?
3. Can I use a traditional flex application with HTMLLoader to accomplish the same goal or does it need to be a full-blown HTML app?

   - If HTMLLoader can be used, would I need to provide the sandbox script bridge meta tags in the iframe tag?

Any help would be very much appreciated at this point. It seems like there are a number of options available, but I'm not sure which path is the right one to pursue at this point in time.

Thank again.

Josh

Answer (score 0):

You have already investigated a lot. I was going to mention Loader.loadBytes technique but you mentioned that it is not secure. Actually, you could take care of security if you knew the signed hashes of the SWFs that may be downloaded. I remember to have read this approach in a AIR team's manager's blog but I can't recollect the link at this time. Basically, the approach would work if you knew all of the SWFs before hand that could be downloaded, and then generated their signed-hashs and put those hashes in an XML which shipped with the initial AIR app. Then, the initial AIR app can download those SWFs, compare their signatures and load them in application sandbox if it matches up with shipped hashes etc.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I hadn't considered signing the SWFs and performing the validation within the AIR application. After some searching, I was able to find a couple of Adobe articles on the subject. @Joe has linked his article in the response below, but I will go ahead and post the other link here as well for future reference for others. http://blogs.adobe.com/emalasky/2008/04/remote_plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

(Long question with lots of points, but here goes)

1. You are correct that passing the Stage object through a script bridge isn't going to work. So, removing the code that accesses the stage and possibly using the script bridge to get the job done in each specific case would be necessary.
2. If you embed the SWF in an HTML page, it will indeed get its own stage. It does not matter whether this is an "HTML-based" AIR application or an ActionScript-based application that uses the HTMLLoader. (Really the two are the same thing.) You don't need an iframe for this. This sounds like the easiest approach, especially if you aren't adding many AIR-specific features.
3. For information on signing, see http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/xml_signatures.html

The other thing I'd look at, if you haven't already, is what facilities Steam offers for doing such updates. Is the turn around time for uploading a new project/update to Steam really greater than the time it would take to add this post-install update system to the app itself? (I hope you aren't in one of those Dilbertian situations where, on paper, it looks like you can save time by doing weird things. In my experience, miracles created by dragging sliders around in Microsoft Project (or the like) don't pan out.)

Comment: Thank you for the response! Since reading your comments, I dug a little deeper into my AIR app utilizing HTMLLoader, and I now have the client successfully loading without the security exceptions, which is great news! Everything appears to be working correctly, save for window resizing events. My approach has been to set the HTMLLoader instance's width and height equal to that of the stage when the NativeWindow is resized. This appears to work fine as I maximize the window size; however, when I minimize the window, the game appears to either stay the same size(scale). Any thoughts?